# How to create Laravel project with docker and connect with local sqlserver db

Tags: sql-server, windows, laravel, docker

How to build Laravel project with Docker, but connect to already created sqlserver database. So I have sqlserver database on my local machine, and I starting container with docker-compose.

`time-track:
    tty: true
    image: bitnami/laravel:6-debian-9
    ports:
      - 3002:3000
    volumes:
      - ../time-track/:/app
    # privileged: true # Privileged mode could be required to run this container under Windows`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom Docker network bridge like:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 my_network
```

_

```
services:
    time-track:
        tty: true
        image: bitnami/laravel:6-debian-9
        ports:
          - 3002:3000
        volumes:
          - ../time-track/:/app
        networks:
          - my_network
networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
```

And using your IP and your port binded for SQLServer ? Is that working ?